# easiest way to get reputation

Tags: support, reputation

What is the easiest way to get reputations? As you guys can see I have one reputation in Stack Exchange and also for Stack Overflow, and I want to learn how to get a lot of reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest and most likely ways for a new user to gain reputation are to:

1. Ask good questions that others will upvote (10 pts)
2. Provide good answers that others will upvote (10 pts) and which may be accepted (15 pts)
3. Suggest good edits that others users will approve (2 pts)

In order to do all of the above make sure that you have taken the [Tour](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour), read at least the first few pages in the [Help](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help) and looked at many Q&As here to see which attract upvotes and which attract downvotes.

Comment: Answering pretty well-known duplicates also works wonder. Come on, there was no need to answer that one and have yet another block in the way of getting the info (duplicate redirection when no answers are posted), rather than simply voting to close and let it die.

Comment: @Jenayah the asker disputed the duplicate that I proposed. This answer does not block this question having a redirection to the duplicates and can be merged into one or other of them by a moderator anyway.

Comment: In this very case, I strongly disagree about answering being OK because OP disputed. They provided no clarification that I can see on how it didn't answer their question, and, well, it does answer it. This answer being upvoted does block automatic redirection to the dupe for logged-out users, and teaches querents not to show research when asking, knowing they'll get answers anyway.